# Create a LINQ query to check to see if the data in the database exists?

Tags: asp.net, linq, postman, webapi

I'm using ASP.NET core and Testing it with Postman WebAPI.

I'm trying to work out the LINQ query which makes it impossible for the user to post the same data if Title and request contains string of “Hope" and "Something" within the database. How do you create a query so when the user posts the same string within the same attributes, it displays a bad request?

As I'm directly doing this in the controller do you need a repository?

Below is my controller and All I need is to be able to query the title attribute and to query it out so only the user enters different string in the database. I've tested it out with postman and it shows 200OK which should show Bad Request when entering the same string in Postman

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using BookingApp.API.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;


using BookingApp.API.Models;


using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace BookingApp.API.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BookController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        public BookController(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooking()
        {
            var Booking = await _context.bookings.Include(c => c.Customer).ToListAsync();

            return Ok(Booking);
        }




        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooking(int id)
        {
            var Booking = await _context.bookings.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

            return Ok(Booking);
        }



        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostBook(Booking bookings, string Title)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var SearchData = await _context.bookings.Where(x => x.Title == Title).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
                if (SearchData != null) 
                    return BadRequest("bad request");
            }


            _context.bookings.Add(bookings);
             _context.SaveChanges();








            return Ok();
        }






        // PUT api/values/5
        // [HttpPut("{id}")]

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPut("{Id}")]
        public Booking PutBooking(int Id, [FromBody] Booking bookings )
        {
            var bookingsInDb = _context.bookings.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == Id);


            bookingsInDb.Title = bookings.Title;
            bookingsInDb.Date = bookings.Date;
            bookingsInDb.Request = bookings.Request;



            _context.SaveChanges();

            return bookingsInDb;

        }

        //

        //


        // }


        {
        }
    }
}
```

This is my model of the Booking

```
using System;

namespace BookingApp.API.Models
{
    public class Booking
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public string Request { get; set; }

        public int NoPeople { get; set; }

        public Customer Customer { get; set;}




    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code, that you have put in images. :)

Comment: Its similar to checking if a username already exists in the database. How would you do that in the controller?